# Why was this question about an animation on a linked page closed?

Tags: support, specific-question, close-reasons

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [What kind of animation is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67389544/what-kind-of-animation-is-used)

I was simply asking for a CSS rule implemented in a particular site which I found online.

Full question text, since the question was deleted:

> ### What kind of animation is used?
>
> What kind of animation is used?I was looking at this website https://example.com/ When i click on the right control, it does some sort of animation(The one where current div vanish at left side). Can anyone tell me how it is achieved?
>
> Thanks

And somehow somebody thinks that I am asking for "recommendation". Why? How?

It was a simple question about CSS transforms/animations. Why did it end up being closed?

Comment: Learn how to use the [debugging capabilities](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), look at the **Inspector** / **Elements** tab, look at each “event” badge next to each element, look at the code in the **Debugger** tab, look at the applied Rules, Animations, etc. in the CSS pane, look at the CSS code in the **Style Editor**. The answer is _basically already there_. It’s open source!

Comment: The [ES spec](//tc39.es/ecma262/), [CSS spec](//www.w3.org/Style/CSS/specs.en.html), [JS docs](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference), [CSS docs](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference), [CSS tutorials](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS), [linters](//jshint.com/about/), [debuggers](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript), [inspectors](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Debugging_HTML), [help center](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), etc. are all available.

Comment: If [_then_, after trying something on your own](/q/261592/4642212), you still have a question, feel free to ask a specific, focused, self-contained question.

Comment: SO strives to be a repository of programming knowledge. Future visitors should also be able to make sense of the answers to a question and have them help them. That's why questions and answer have to be self-contained and should not rely on links to external resources.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thanks for taking time to put these comments. I tried to debug that   but animation is moving fast, i can't able to see what's happening.

Though i'll try to give it another shot.

Comment: @php.prg - btw, devtools (at least in chrome) can slow down animations on replay (see [screenshot of the control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2g9Vj.png))

Comment: @JeanneDark I understand that but i guess it is sad, that if my question helps other people than it is alright but if my question only helps myself then that question doesn't deserve to be on this platform. :(

Comment: Maybe it's sad that you prefer questions that only help yourself, instead of questions that can both help you **and** can help other users.

Comment: @yivi Haha, so next time if i stuck in a problem i should go on a treasure hunt to see if other people got that same problem then ask question here on SO. WOW!

Jokes apart On serious note, I think every user should be given some time at least couple of hours before any moderator close the question as normal user put their faith in the community.

Comment: No need to go on a treasure hunt. Just pose a the question in way that's useful for future visitors. Or, you know, just not use SO to ask your issues. Whatever floats your boat.

Comment: @php.prg Yes, exactly. I’ve already linked to _“How much research effort …”_. Stack Overflow is a repository of useful question–answer pairs that help future readers so that every developer can benefit from the knowledge. Stack Overflow _really isn’t_ a one-on-one help desk or a forum where each thread only helps a single person; Stack Exchange was created _exactly to not be that_. _“every user should be given some time”_ — see [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](/q/260263/4642212).

Answer (score 18):

To begin with, the question cannot be answered without visiting a linked page. A question like that is automatically off-topic on this site. All posts need to be self-contained, and not need visiting external resources to be understood.

That the site is external (e.g. not another SO post) just makes it worse, since it makes it potentially suspect of being spam.

If the question included some sort of capture of the desired effect, a basic HTML markup, and it simply asked "how can I create *this* animation on *this* element using CSS only", it would be basically on-topic.

The question could still possibly (probably) be a dupe. Or still be downvoted if users found it poor/not useful; but that's a different thing altogether.

The "recommendation" close reason is probably not accurate. But users likely used it because answering the question required visiting off-site links. "Missing debugging details" (even if not a debugging question) or "needs clarity" would probably be more accurate, but reopening a question just to close it again for the *right* reason is considered a waste of time.

Comment: Ok i didn't knew about "external link make it off-topic" but i see all the jsfiddle codepen etc link on the questions and answers here on stackoverflow, so i thought it is ok to post a link, which will give a right idea whoever is looking at the question.

So the closed reason is wrong, and i had known how that css was working i had put some code in there, but i had no idea what is happening on that site :(

Comment: It's not "external links make it off-topic". Is: "having to click on a link to be able to answer the question"

Answer (score 12):

We are not going to do the reverse engineering /detective work for you, specially not on off-site sites. You might as well be here for just promoting said site.

If you find something in the wild you want to implement you start fresh with markup and CSS content you *think* could work. You base your work on documentation found on MDN or SO or other sites / training materials / books.

Once you have something going but get stuck in the process, it is time to post a question on Stack Overflow. We're happy to add some extra CSS/JavaScript/Haskell/PHP to what you've provided already to achieve your final goal.

Your Stack Overflow question was correctly closed.

Comment: Haha i am not saying people should do do the reverse engineering /detective work for me, all i wanted was to put in the right direction not a [closed] question just after i posted the question. 

Saying that, If my  question is not helping me or any other person, i would have deleted it by myself,  i guess any other user would do the same.

Comment: @php.prg what is the right direction? The animation could have been created with an animated GIF, an webp video source, some clever javascript to load 25 images, some javascript to Draw on the Canvas, some CSS 2.0 tricks to pretend animation or proper CSS Animation rules or God forbid: a Flash animation. I need to reverse engineer it for the "right" direction.

Answer (score 8):

Since [rene's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407598/11407695) and [yivi's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407599/11407695) answers address the main reason for closure, I will address the post itself. Let's take a look at it for it is likely to be deleted shortly (in fact, it already is):

> I was looking at this website https://caferati.me/ When i click on the right control, it
> does some sort of animation(The one where current div vanish at left side). Can anyone
> tell me how it is achieved?
>
> Thanks

There are two issues with it (in order of severity):

1. The question requires the reader to go to a website and do something there. We want the posts to be sufficient on their own - imagine 10 years from now someone chances on your post, but the domain in question went down. Now the only thing they see is the "some sort of animation" part and have no way of understanding what you saw back then.
2. We do not care about "thanks" - the only thing an answerer needs from you is an upvote if their answer is helpful and an "accept" if theirs is *the most* helpful one.

If you trim out what's mentioned above, this is what is left of your post (editorial changes made for readability):

> I was looking at a website. When I click on the right control, it does some sort of animation (The one where the current div vanishes on the left side). How is it achieved?

Can this reasonably be answered? No, there is little information that could allow the answerer to identify the animation, hence the closure.

Comment: @SebastianSimon - I need more coffee :) Thanks, my mind is so unused to somebody referring to elements disappearing as "vanishing" that, lacking proper `<name>` wrap my mind read this as a typo of "dev vanishing"

Comment: Thanks for the detail, i didn't know that an external link is an off-topic and not sure if jsfiddle or similar link also consider off-topic or not.

And clearly there's no profit for me if anybody go to that site atleast for me other than if i learn something.

Also i guess site is probably safe as it is mentioned in freecodecamp site which help other people to learn about programming.

Anyways, would you like to recommend if i got in such a special case how should i ask it on stackoverflow, when i have limited data?

Comment: @php.prg - I will add a link a bit later, we have a good longread on that. Btw, sorry for misreading the "div" part, my brain got confused :) P.s. The gist of the "no link" policy is tied to us wanting the questions/answers to serve other readers as well. If SO was a help desk then sure, one-off questions -> one-off answers, but we at least try to get some lasting value out of posts (and there is a huge amount of them, so that's all about keeping things manageable in the long run) [1/2]

Comment: @php.prg See [How to create Stack Snippets](/q/358992/4642212). You can insert the HTML, CSS, and JS code there; make sure to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](/help/mcve). (Oh, sorry, commented right between Oleg’s \[1/2\] and \[2/2\]…)

Comment: [2/2] So when you ask the reader to go to a website, it is not like we think your intentions are malicious (we have mechanisms for dealing with that), or that the site is unsafe to visit (although some people *do* care about that). It is that when the site eventually dies, any other visitor of your Q&A is left dead in the water. They are lucky if there is an answer, but if your post goes unnoticed (and there are a ton of those due to the sheer number of posts added every day), the question becomes unreproducible.

Comment: It's not just "when the site eventually dies". They would stay alive but change their site completely :)

Comment: @SebastianSimon - I usually include those references to account exactly for the possibility of this happening :) Scratte - yes, or that, it is even more illustrative since design changes happen often, so, in the long run, who knows will there be an animation or not.

Comment: It's worse than that. The design could be changed only a bit, there could _still_ be have an animation, but it could be changed ever so slightly to make all the answers irrelevant and confusing. Or maybe it has the same animation, but the underlying HTML changed. Or maybe nothing changed at all, but the answers are wrong and a future visitor has no way of knowing if the answers are wrong because they can't know if the linked page changed or not.